# CIFourfoldRotatedTile Core Image Filter

Tags: ios, ios6, core-image

Following is the code that i am trying to apply to get CIFourfoldRotatedTile  filter on image but i am getting a nil image in output.

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];               // 1
CIImage *aimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"].CGImage];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFourfoldRotatedTile"];           // 3
[filter setValue:aimage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)] forKey:@"inputCenter"];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50] forKey:@"inputWidth"];

CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];              // 4
CGRect extent = [result extent];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
self.imgview.image = finalImage;
```

Don't know which parameter i am entering wrong. Please guide me on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked your code and found that `extent` is infinite here i.e. you are getting a `nil` image. I just made a little change here, give extent to your frame

```
CGRect extent = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

OR

```
CGRect extent = [aimage extent];
```

and then try.

Comment: extent contains output image size so that means my output image is not properly getting created using the filter

Comment: I think I'm right. You should use `[aimage extent]` instead of `[result extent]`

Comment: Actually I have also tried `CIGaussianBlur` and `[result extent]` doesn't come correct even you can test it with default values too. Don't fill anything just try with default values then see.

Comment: at the end i want output image rect not input image rect

Comment: And may I know what was that ? @Leena